# How can replace all case in value of column using linq.js?

Tags: linq, linq.js

I using linq.js and i want replace single quotes when searching data.
This my code.

```
var list = [
            { a: "50", b: 4, c: 1 },
            { a: "60", b: 3, c: 7 },
            { a: "'540'", b: 3, c: 3 }
           ];
var val = "'540'";
val = val.replace(/'/g, "&apos;");
var res = Enumerable.From(list).Where("($.a).replace(\"'\",\"&apos;\")=='" + val + "'").ToArray();
```

If there is only 1 single quote in the data, it works.
But if there are 2 single quote in it, it can't search.

Comment: I don't know linq.js but I think it's going to be simpler / less confusing to use its lambda syntax rather than eval-string syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, linq.js the same code in javascript.
I have to use regex to replace:
It is ok , if i change to :

```
 var res = Enumerable.From(list).Where("($.a).replace(\/'\/g,\"&apos;\")=='" + val + "'").ToArray();
```